# Where to put SPF record

Tags: dns, spf

This may be a silly question but I have no knowledge of configuring domains and need some help. My situation is as follows:

1. I own a domain, let's say myexampledomain.com, bought from vendor A.
2. My website is physically hosted on the server B. My domain is configured to redirect to this server.
3. I also have an email account, let's say office at myexampledomain.com, bought from vendor C.

I want the website to send emails through my email account using SMTP, so as I understand I have to add a SPF record somewhere. And this is the question - where should I put a SPF record? Is my domain's configuration the right place? Isn't redirection a problem?

And the second question - is a SPF record like that enough?

v=spf1 a mx ip4:X.X.X.X a:mail.vendorc.com -all

Comment: Generally speaking it's not a good to mix with several vendors just to save a few bucks!? But you have to change it in the dns that holds the MX-pointer.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld I didn't want to go into such details. I will end up with two vendors after I make sure everything works well - domain registrar and hosting/mail vendor.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld there are many very good reasons to have different vendors for each of these services, cost being just one.

Comment: @matthew - what would the other reasons be?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld, Features. A good web host is not necessarily a good email host. I'd much rather use multiple vendors who each are top in their area of expertise, than to use a single vendor that is mediocre at everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You would change it with the vendor that provides DNS service for `myexampledomain.com` which could be any of your vendors. To find out, start with vendor A where you bought the domain name, you'll be able to see there if your DNS name servers have been set to one of the other vendors.

2) SPF is not required in order to send email. All other things being equal it may help with deliverability of your email since receivers have more to go on when determining if they should trust your server. It will also reduce the chance that someone else tries to use your domain name for spam.

3) Your example SPF is not unreasonable but there's not nearly enough info in your question to say if it is correct. You should probably start with vendor C and see what they say you should set your SPF record to, and then modify it to add any other servers that will be sending mail on your behalf.

Comment: Although SPF is not required in order to send email, I am suddenly finding that I can no longer email people with gmail accounts.